# SQL запрос на удаление всех записией с определенной рубрики WP

Tags: sql, wordpress

В чем ошибка SQL кода который должен удалять все записи с определенной рубрики у которой id - 139?

Он удаляет записи но и удаляет рубрики!

Допустим:

Авто - рубрика id 20

- Грузовые - рубрика id 21
- Запись в рубрике грузовые

При указании рубрики с id 20 он удаляет внутри 21 рубрику и запись то же а если указать id 21 то есть рубрику "Грузовые" то он все равно удалить рубрику и запись внутри нее!

```
DELETE tb1,tb2,tb3,tb4
FROM wp_posts tb1
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tb2 ON ( tb1.ID = tb2.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta tb3 ON ( tb1.ID = tb3.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tb4 ON ( tb4.term_taxonomy_id = tb2.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms tb5 ON ( tb5.term_id = tb4.term_id )
WHERE tb5.term_id = 139
```

А мне нужно удалить только все записи а рубрики должны остаться.

Comment: Думаю следует импортировать рубрики, затем удалить, затем экспортировать. Это тоже вариант, но разового.

Answer (score 3):

Если вам нужно удалить записи из таблицы, то её и указывайте в предложении `from`, а связи с рубриками задавайте в предложении `where`, типа

```
delete from t1
where id in(...)
```

**Обновление**

Если код генерирует система, то тут я не помогу. Вообще говоря, диалект странный - перечисление таблиц после `DELETE`.  Тем не менее, записи удаляются из таблицы. Чтобы написать нормальный запрос, нужно знать структуру БД, а не гадать.

Comment: Мне нужно удалить запись не из определенной таблицы а из определенной рубрики скажите пожалуйста ваш код это же не полный код для чего же указанно LEFT JOIN

Comment: Нельзя за один запрос явно удалить записи из нескольких таблиц (можно неявно, если объявлен foreign key с ограничением типа cascade delete)